# VMware View and DRS

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-view

We are currently using VMware Horizon View for our VDI deployment and I was trying to find something on what are the best practices on using or not using DRS in our View environment?

Comment: Have you done any research at all on this topic?

Comment: Yes I have and I cant seem to find anything out on Google or VMware's website that says here are HA and DRS best practices for a View enviornment

Comment: Voting to reopen because the best-practices for HA/DRS on vSphere with VDI aren't well-known. I only know because I've had to observe cluster behavior in production and adjusted settings to make sense for the environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For VDI (VMware View), my recommendation is to enable HA on your cluster as with any virtualized workload. That's a key feature of vSphere and makes sense to have on.

For DRS, understand your workload a bit. How many hosts will you have? How many VMs? How tight is the consolidation?

I'd say that the activity on virtualized desktops is not as predictable as an environment comprised entirely of servers. Spiky on the resource side. My understanding is that it makes sense to lower the DRS policy to "Conservative" to only migrate systems based on maintenance needs *if* you have a high level of consolidation. If not, possibly use the default or slightly more aggressive DRS automation setting.

Also see: [**Best Practices: Configuration of VMware vSphere DRS with VDI**](http://blog.atlantiscomputing.com/2014/02/best-practices-for-configuration-of-vmware-vsphere-drs-with-vdi/)

Comment: +1 This is my best practice for Citrix VDI. As mentioned, VDI workloads are a lot harder to predict accurately than a server, and continual VMotions will impact your users considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Ideologically this doesn't really make sense.  The whole point of VDI being that you have disposable machines and all.  DRS and HA shouldn't be the least bit necessary.

Comment: Yeah, this answer doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: This is over simplified, but non persistent VDI benefits far less from DRS and HA if you have an N+1 build.